# In IPython how to execute a command every line

Tags: python, ipython

I was wondering if it's possible to execute a command for every line is typed.

Would be great to be able to switch it on/off.

My application is to send a "renew" command to a GUI during debugging. 
Also interesting maybe to pipe what one is typing to a file etc.

examlpe:

```
In [1]: h.Draw("E","","")
Out[1]: 1922L
In [2]: h1.Draw("E","","same")
Out[2]: 1234L
In [3]: rt.gPad.Modified();rt.gPad.Update()
In [4]: h2.Draw("E","","same")
Out[4]: 3214L
In [5]: rt.gPad.Modified();rt.gPad.Update()
```

convert to:

```
In [1]: startUpdating()
In [2]: h.Draw("E","","")
Out[2]: 1922L
In [3]: h1.Draw("E","","same")
Out[3]: 1234L
In [4]: h2.Draw("E","","same")
Out[4]: 3214L
```

Comment: Aren't you just describing the difference between an interactive session and running a script?

Comment: not quite, I think. in an interactive session there is no automation, hence it is only executed, what is typed. I'd like to customise the interactive session.

Comment: *"it is only executed, what is typed"* - as opposed to... what, exactly? What do you see as the *point* of this; what are you trying to achieve? What GUI are you trying to debug? How are you running it now, and what problems is that causing?

Comment: added an example. 
in pyroot I need to renew the TCanvas after a draw in a specific usage case

Comment: `get_ipython().events.register('pre_run_cell', func)` will register a a function to be called before each chunk of code you enter. Change 'pre' to 'post' if you want it to run after the code you type.

Comment: ok, good approach, did not work ad hoc for me (2.7 vs. 3.0?). it leads to the solution and duplicate though! thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ipython customize prompt to display cell run time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150661/ipython-customize-prompt-to-display-cell-run-time)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite automatic, but you can define a custom line magic to make it easier to perform the reset.

```
In [1]: from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic

In [2]: @register_line_magic
   ...: def renew(line):
   ...:     rt.gPad.Modified()
   ...:     rt.gPad.Update()
   ...:

In [3]: startUpdating()
In [4]: h.Draw("E","","")
Out[4]: 1922L
In [5]: %renew
In [6]: h1.Draw("E","","same")
Out[6]: 1234L
In [7]: %renew
In [8]: h2.Draw("E","","same")
Out[8]: 3214L
```

Comment: I can as well define a short-named method and use it after every .Draw
I was hoping IPython was more flexible to allow automation

Comment: Based on the `%%timeit` magic, I assume there's a way to define something similar that would call your reset code after each line supplied to, say,  `%%renew`. Still not quite what you are looking for, but perhaps some research into IPython's magic system will turn something up.

Answer (score 0):

for now I'm wrapping the Draw method

```
def ReDraw(self,*args, **kwargs):
      self.Draw(*args, **kwargs)
      rt.gPad.Modified()
      rt.gPad.Update()

rt.TTree.ReDraw = ReDraw
h.ReDraw("E","","")
```

it's not quite what is requested, I hope there is a IPython-specific way too